# how to export VB project to dll

Tags: vb6, dllexport

Is there any way to export VB project to DLL? I just found only way to export VB project (VB6) as .exe file. Please help me if you have experience about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an [ActiveX Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229332%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) using Visual Basic 6 instead of an Application Project.

> Components provide reusable code in the form of objects. An application that uses a component’s code, by creating objects and calling their properties and methods, is referred to as a *client*.
>
> Components can run either in-process or out-of-process with respect to the clients that use their objects. An in-process component, or ActiveX DLL, runs in another application’s process. The client may be the application itself, or another in-process component that the application is using.

Note that if you were going to reference this DLL created by VB6 to a VB.Net Project, you need to add something in your VB.Net Code. [Here's a really good tutorial explaining that.](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/85026-how-to-create-a-dll-using-visual-basic-60/#post_id_535945)